# How to make the translations work with the Python 3 "format" built-in method in Odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, format, odoo, translation, odoo-12

Since Python v3, [format](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string-formatting) is the primary API method to make variable substitutions and value formatting. However, [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/reference/translations.html) is still using the Python 2 approach with the `%s` wildcard.

```python
message = _('Scheduled meeting with %s') % invitee.name

# VS

message = 'Scheduled meeting with {}'.format(invitee.name)  # this is not translated
```

I have seen some parts of the Odoo code where they have used some workaround, isolating strings.

```python
exc = MissingError(
    _("Record does not exist or has been deleted.")
    + '\n\n({} {}, {} {})'.format(_('Records:'), (self - existing).ids[:6], _('User:'), self._uid)
)
```

But, does anybody know if there is a more convenient way to use the format method and make it work with translations?

Answer (score 0):

`_` return a string, so you can call format on it directly.

```
  _("{} Sequence").format(sec.code)
```

or like this:

```
 _("{code} Sequence").format(code=invitee.code)
```

when you export the translation in `PO` file you should see this for the second example:

```
   # for FR translation you should not translate the special format expression
   msgid "{code} Sequence"
   msgstr "{code} Séquence"
```

and this for the first example:

```
  msgid "{} Sequence"
  msgstr "{} Séquence"
```

If you don't see this then Odoo must be checking that `_()` must not be followed by `.` so you can work around this by doing this for example by surrounding the expression by parentheses :

```
   # I think + "" is not needed 
   ( _("{} Séquence") + "").format(sec.code)
```

Because In python `"this {}".format("expression")` is the same as this `("this {}").format("expression")`